# How to access variables outside of map function?

Tags: reactjs

Have looped over some data in my applicaition but I was wondering if I could access variables outside the map function?

I am trying to read a count of my data, however the object.unit_test_count(which is shown in asteriks) is coming back as object is not defined? How do I access that unit_test_count from the objectsToShow.map function? (also shown in asteriks)

```
<div className={getGridClassName()} style={{backgroundColor: 'var(--main-color)', color: '#fff', fontWeight: '500'}}>
        <div />
      **<div>Object{object.unit_test_count}</div>**
        <div />
        {props.location.pathname === '/requesttest' ?
          <React.Fragment>
            <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}># Unit Tests</div>
            <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>Select</div>
          </React.Fragment>
          :
          <React.Fragment>
            <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>Passes</div>
            <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>Fails</div>
            <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
              <Tooltip title={'hello'}>Errors<InfoIcon/>
              </Tooltip>
            </div>
            <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>N/A<InfoIcon /></div>


            <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}># Units Tests</div>
          </React.Fragment>
        }
      </div>

      {!objectsToShow ? null : **objectsToShow.map(object =>**
        <div key={object.object} className={getGridClassName(object)}>
          <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}>
            <Tooltip title={object.relation.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + object.relation.substr(1).toLowerCase()}>
              <div className='RelationInitialBox' style={{backgroundColor: getRelationColor(object.relation)}}>
                {object.relation.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}
              </div>  
            </Tooltip>
          </div>
          <div 
            className='ClickableText' 
            style={{wordBreak: 'break-all'}} 
            onClick={() => onObjectClick(object.object)}
          >
            {object.object}
          </div>
          <div>{object.is_critical ? 'Critical' : ''}</div>
          {props.location.pathname === '/requesttest' ?
            <React.Fragment>
              <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>{object.unit_test_count}</div> 
              <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                <Checkbox mainColor changeHandler={props.handleObjectsCheckbox} data={object} />
              </div>
            </React.Fragment>
            :
            <React.Fragment>
              <div style={{color: 'green', textAlign: 'center'}}>{object.unit_test_passes}</div>
              <div style={{color: 'red', textAlign: 'center'}}>{object.unit_test_fails}</div>
              <div style={{color: 'red', textAlign: 'center'}}>{object.unit_test_errors}</div>
              <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>{object.unit_test_not_applicable}</div>
              <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>{object.unit_test_count}</div>

            </React.Fragment>
          }
        </div>
      )}
```

Update syntax error:

[Syntax error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kT7Le.png)

```
    objectsToShow.map(item =>
    <div className='Card' style={{overflow: 'visible'}}>
      

      <div className={getGridClassName()} style={{backgroundColor: 'var(--main-color)', color: '#fff', fontWeight: '500'}}>
        <div />
      <div>Object{item.unit_test_count}</div>
        <div />
        {props.location.pathname === '/requesttest' ?
          <React.Fragment>
            <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}># Unit Tests</div>
            <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>Select</div>
          </React.Fragment>
          :
          <React.Fragment>
            <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>Passes</div>
            <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>Fails</div>
            <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
              <Tooltip title={'hello'}>Errors<InfoIcon/>
              </Tooltip>
            </div>
            <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>N/A<InfoIcon /></div>


            <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}># Units Tests</div>
          </React.Fragment>
        }
      </div>
    )

      {!objectsToShow ? null : objectsToShow.map(object =>
        <div key={object.object} className={getGridClassName(object)}>
          <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-end'}}>
            <Tooltip title={object.relation.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + object.relation.substr(1).toLowerCase()}>
              <div className='RelationInitialBox' style={{backgroundColor: getRelationColor(object.relation)}}>
                {object.relation.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}
              </div>  
            </Tooltip>
          </div>
          <div 
            className='ClickableText' 
            style={{wordBreak: 'break-all'}} 
            onClick={() => onObjectClick(object.object)}
          >
            {object.object}
          </div>
          <div>{object.is_critical ? 'Critical' : ''}</div>
          {props.location.pathname === '/requesttest' ?
            <React.Fragment>
              <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>{object.unit_test_count}</div> 
              <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                <Checkbox mainColor changeHandler={props.handleObjectsCheckbox} data={object} />
              </div>
            </React.Fragment>
            :
            <React.Fragment>
              <div style={{color: 'green', textAlign: 'center'}}>{object.unit_test_passes}</div>
              <div style={{color: 'red', textAlign: 'center'}}>{object.unit_test_fails}</div>
              <div style={{color: 'red', textAlign: 'center'}}>{object.unit_test_errors}</div>
              <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>{object.unit_test_not_applicable}</div>
              <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>{object.unit_test_count}</div>

            </React.Fragment>
          }
        </div>
      )}

      <PageNumbers pageNumbersList={pageNumbers} currentPage={currentPage} onClick={onPageNumberClick} />
    </div>
  )
})

objectsView.propTypes = {
  objects: PropTypes.array,
  status: PropTypes.oneOf(['', 'Failed', 'Success', 'Unresolved']),
  onObjectClick: PropTypes.func,
  handleObjectsCheckbox: PropTypes.func
}

export default withRouter(objectsView)
```

Comment: You can access *any* variable so long as it is in [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope); be that block scope, function scope, class scope, file scope, etc... What and where is `object` defined/declared?

Comment: I'm quite lost in your example and I suppose others will be too. Please provide a contrieved example as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. This looks much like an app clinic problem now and more suitabe for a hands-on dev class question. Your example should contain a simple collection, the map function applied to it and some vars in the outer scope to play with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this below line,

```
<div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>{object.unit_test_count}</div>
```

map() will check for the property on the variable name you passed to map at

```
 {!objectsToShow ? null : **objectsToShow.map(object =>**
```

So you can change that variable name to something else.

Or

You can assign `object.unit_test_count` to any other variable and use it inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks, can you show me an example of what you mean by changing the variable name?

Comment: **objectsToShow.map(object =>** in this line change `object`  to any other variable name and use it as ` <div key={variableName.object} className={getGridClassName(variableName)}>` inside the map function. and for getting the unit_test_count you can `object.unit_test_count`

Comment: thank you, I have updated the code and I am getting a syntax error, however, could you please help me :)

Comment: you probably missing closing <div>. Please check your code and remove `})` this before `objectsView.propTypes = {` line.